# How to set rules 'Not in my Contacts' mail on my MacOS Ventura M1

Tags: mail.app

I've recently moved from Thunderbird to Apple Mail and am setting up some rules / filters. In TBird I could set a rule "Not in my Contacts" but that doesn't seem to be available in Apple Mail. Am I missing something? If that is not possible that means I have to enter EVERY possible email or server that might send me spam. Not a very good solution.

Comment: OMG. How did I miss that. DUH. Thanks eh!

Answer (score 1):

The criteria "Sender is in my contacts" and "Sender is not in my contacts" are both options that are available as criteria along with many more options.  Just open the first drop down and you'll find the list (shown below).

[image]